# Slideshow Loop with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

This is the JavaScript I have for a website publishing software. This Script works fine if I want to just run the script one time.

I'm looking to add to this script to loop it and make it run over and over again.

Here is the script I have right now...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pause = 3000;
function autoPresenter(){ xr_next(); 
setTimeout("autoPresenter();", pause); }
setTimeout("autoPresenter();", pause);
</script>
```

Thank you for any assistance. The use of this is a slide show presentation that is being displayed at a trade show and I obviously don't want to be there to restart it everytime it finishes.

Cheers,

Glen

Comment: Obivously your timeout loop is infinite [as it is](http://jsfiddle.net/4cSX2/), since you can't stop  an anonymous timeout in `xr_next()` function. If the slideshow stops, the reason is somewhere else than in this code. Probably you show the last frame again and again, or an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `xr_next()` is doing, but I'd use an index argument in one of your functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pause = 3000;
    var currIndex = 0;
    var itemCount = 10;

    function autoPresenter()
    {
         if (currIndex > itemCount) currIndex = 0;
         xr_next(currIndex);
         currIndex++;
         setTimeout(autoPresenter, pause);
    }

    autoPresenter();
</script>
```

Comment: this script unfortunately did not have any effect. the xr_next I believe refers to the to the programs value for the next slide. i'm not sure if this is any help. you suggestion is much appreciated.